# Avoid duplicate entries based on multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I am trying to get rid of duplicate entries from the following result set:

```
ID  Name    missionID   teamID  eventTimestamp  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:04  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:04  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:04  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:04  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:06  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:06  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:06  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:07  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:07  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:08  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:08
```

For each combination of targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID and eventTimestamp I only want 1 entry. So I want the result set to look like this instead of the above:

```
targetID    targetName  missionID   teamID  eventTimestamp  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:04  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:06  
25  C   1000415147500265653 2   02-11-2014 14:07  
25  C   1000415147500265653 1   02-11-2014 14:08
```

As you can see. there can be other entries with the same combination of targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID but with a different timestamp - and I need to keep these, so I can't just run a max or min date on  this. I have tried using distinct, ranking and group by but nothing seems to work, I keep getting duplicate entries. If I use max or min on date I only get one entry per targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID - and that is not what I want

My original query just to get the duplicate result set is this:

```
select targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID, eventTimestamp from (
select a.characterID, a.targetID, a.targetName, a.missionID, b.teamID as teamID, a.eventTimestamp from events_live a
left join (
select distinct characterID, teamID from events_live where eventName = 'missionStarted' or eventName = 'characterCreated') b on a.characterID = b.characterID 

where eventName ='missionObjective' and a.eventTimestamp > '2014-10-31' and a.eventTimestamp < '2014-11-07' and objectiveName = 'Capture' and (targetID ='25' or targetID='26' or targetID ='27' or targetID = '28' or targetID = '29') and b.teamID is not null
order by missionID, targetID, eventTimestamp
)t1

order by missionID, targetID, eventTimestamp
```

I've tried doing another select with group by targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID, eventTimestamp on top of the original - and I still get duplicates. I have tried running distinct on eventTimestamp, but it still doesn't give me what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID, date_trunc('minute',eventTimestamp ) AS eventTimestamp
FROM (
    SELECT a.characterID, a.targetID, a.targetName, a.missionID, b.teamID as teamID, a.eventTimestamp 
    FROM events_live a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT distinct characterID, teamID from events_live 
        WHERE eventName = 'missionStarted' 
        OR eventName = 'characterCreated') b 
    ON a.characterID = b.characterID     
    WHERE eventName ='missionObjective' 
    AND a.eventTimestamp > '2014-10-31' 
    AND a.eventTimestamp < '2014-11-07' 
    AND objectiveName = 'Capture' 
    AND (
        targetID ='25' 
        OR targetID='26' 
        OR targetID ='27' 
        OR targetID = '28' 
        OR targetID = '29') 
    AND b.teamID IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY missionID, targetID, eventTimestamp) t1
GROUP BY targetID, targetName, missionID, teamID, eventTimestamp    
ORDER BY missionID, targetID, eventTimestamp
```

Edit: date_trunc('minute',eventTimestamp ) should do the trick

Comment: Ok, but it is in itslef a large query with joins to even get the duplicate result set:

Comment: Update my answer, by using the above query you dont get the right result?

Comment: I still get duplicates :-(

Comment: @LeneJungKjær Did you try my answer ?

Comment: @Houari I would like to know whats the result of the queries both of yours and mine. Since a GROUP BY should normally work as expected... Don't get it why it's not working ^^

Comment: None of your suggestions work. I am starting to suspect that the eventTimestamp although only showing date hours, minutes and seconds might have som milliseconds or something attached to it, so that the dates really aren't duplicates after all - I will look into this and get back to you. Thanks though, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @LeneJungKjær You are right. Doc. says: "When timestamp values are stored as eight-byte integers (currently the default), microsecond precision is available over the full range of values"

Comment: Now it works - thanks a lot, how stupid that the problem was due to the datetime format. I couldn't for the life of me understand why group by didn't work!

Comment: @LeneJungKjær Since you output "02-11-2014 14:04" in your question it was not really clear. Try next time to be more precise.

Comment: I will, sorry - I'm not used to posting questions like this :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX_NAME ON TABLE_NAME(COL1, COL2,...);
```

This would resolve the issue.